# Trouble with time in `setInterval`

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with time. Idk what, but something goes wrong bcz i every single itteration of my function the time is "reducing".

So, i have a function, which changes the label's text. The hole function's duration - 19sec.
(From 0s To 4s) - "Text 1"
(From 4s To 11s) - "Text 2"
(From 11s To 19s) - "Text 3"

Then it repeats. And after a couple of itterations the label changes from "Text 1" to "Text 2" for less than 4s (~3s - ~3.5s)

```
function TextChanger() {

    clearInterval(timer);

    timer = setInterval((i => () => {

        const parts = { 0: 'Text 1', 4: 'Text 2', 11: 'Text 3' };

        if (parts[i]) console.log(parts[i]);

            else console.log(i); // 1s, 2s, 3s has passed

        i++;
        i %= 19;

    })(0), 1000);

}
```

**Thanks**

Comment: What calls TextChanger? And what's the point of an IIFE that takes a parameter that's ignored?

Comment: I don't see a problem when running your listed code, everything is logged about every second as would be expected and each element of your object is logged when `i` is the appropriate value. I don't see anything _"reducing"_. Are you possibly calling TextChanger() more than once thus making multiple `setInterval` calls that are operating on the same variable/elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the function for a little while in the Chrome Console and got these results consistently:

```
Text 1
1
2
3
Text 2
5
6
7
8
9
10
Text 3
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
Text 1...
```

It may be an issue outside your function, an issue specific to your browser, or I don't understand your problem.

I rewrote your code how I would write it, try this format instead:

```js
function TextChanger() {
    clearInterval(timer)
    var i = 0;
    timer = setInterval( () => {
        const parts = { 0: 'Text 1', 4: 'Text 2', 11: 'Text 3' };

        if (parts[i])
            console.log(parts[i]);
        else
            console.log(i); // 1s, 2s, 3s has passed

        i++;
        i %= 19;
    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It do might be browser)

Answer (score 2):

timers are not reliable since they execute in the main thread with relatively low priority. Set it to run at 900 ms and calculate the time from the last change.

Comment: So i should change 1000 to 900?

Comment: well it depends how acurate you want it to be. If it is visual only keep it at 1s. if you want to be sure, set at 500ms. At the end the work is done by the .totalSecons() call, the timer interval simply gives you the frequency you do the check

Comment: I ran it at 10 and I can't see a problem even after 100th iteration for all three texts. I have no other application (aside from Win10's standard threads running). The timer value only states that the next tick doesn't come until AT LEAST x ms have passed and not exactly after x ms have past

Comment: Yea, may be it's all because of my browser. Thanks a lot